# My prepared statement returns "null"

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I was reading up on preventing SQL injection and i tried to convert my code. Before I changed it, when the page was loaded, I would update my sql with whatever was in `'input[name="amount"]'` and change the text of the id "freetexts" to whatever `echo json_encode($result);` gave out. Now after I changed it, the value of freetexts keeps getting changed to "null"

here is my php

```
<?php
$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";
$amount = $_POST["amount"];


$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      exit();
   }

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE freetexts SET amount = amount - ? WHERE 1")) {
}
/* Bind parameters: s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $amount);

//$update = "UPDATE freetexts SET amount = amount - '$amount' WHERE 1";
/* Execute it */
      $stmt -> execute();

      /* Bind results */
      $stmt -> bind_result($result);

      /* Fetch the value */
      $stmt -> fetch();

echo json_encode($result);

      /* Close statement */
      $stmt -> close();


?>
```

And here is my javascript

```
    var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            amount: amount
        },
        url: 'textlimit.php',
        success: function(data) { //Receives the data from the php code
            document.getElementById('freetexts').innerHTML = "Current FREE texts left: " + data;
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a Update-Query. A Update has no resultset.

Comment: I thought I was fetching the results with fetch();?

Comment: Yes and No. fetch() fetches results, yes. But there **are no results** to fetch, since you told the database to update your data but NOT to send you a result back. update will NOT send you your data back. The only thing, update can or will send you, are the affected rows. If you want your data, you have to ask for it, means, you have to write your select.

Comment: On top of what @tkausl said, the only way to check that the query worked is to check the `num_rows` and see if it's more than `1` (not `0`)

Comment: @Darren this depends heavily on how you define "worked". For example, you have a table 'users' which holds the username, password and points you can get by doing something. Lets say, you are a friendly person and you want to give everyone 10 points for free. So you write your update 'UPDATE users SET points=points+10'. The problem is now, you **have** no users, so the affected rows (num_rows) is 0. Does this now mean, your query did not work? This is maybe not the best example but there are querys, you just want update **if** something is true but you don't care if it really changed something.

Comment: Thats a great point @tkausl, was just thinking in terms of the OP's query!

Comment: @Dgameman1 Well, this depends on if you want all rows or just a subset or one of them. By the way, this ```WHERE 1``` does literally nothing, its like a ```if(true)``` in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tkausl and @Darren, I've realized that no where in my code actually selects the row I want. I also learned that `WHERE 1` does literally nothing. This is the revised php and it works perfectly but I also doubt it's optimized. Any ideas on what I could do to make the code better? Such as removing `$stmt -> fetch();` if it's unnecessary

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "XXX");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "XXX");
define('DB_DATABASE', "XXX");


$amount = $_POST["amount"];


$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
      exit();
   }

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE freetexts SET amount = amount - ?")) {

/* Bind parameters: s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $amount);

/* Execute it */
      $stmt -> execute();

      /* Bind results */
      $stmt -> bind_result($result);

      /* Fetch the value */
      $stmt -> fetch();



      /* Close statement */
      $stmt -> close();
      }

$query = "SELECT `amount` FROM `freetexts`";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo json_encode($row["amount"]);  
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: actually the correct way to check whether a row has been updated is `->affected_rows > 0` not `->num_rows`

Comment: When I change it to affect rows, the text I get back is "0 results"

Comment: i'm referring on update, of course on selected row, then `num_rows` respectively